# Managing Text for multiple launguages

Tags: android, localization

I have to check the word 'DEBITED' and 'CREDITED' and this can be in multiple languages.

This word are different for different countries. Now, How can I check for that ?

Have I to manage for several conditions at my side or any google api is available to manage such things ?

Thanks.

Comment: if these words are coming from your server then don't compare with strings, compare with integers(i.e. 0 for CREDITED and 1 for DEBITED).

Comment: Sir, I have to check for such words from incoming messages(SMS) in device for all countries. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add multi pal string.xml file for multipal languages in values folder according there country code.

[Supporting Different Languages and Cultures](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use different strings into respected languages and place them in appropriate strings.xml files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to add multi string file for example in the rep values-fr add string.xml and make supportRTL in your manifest file